# How to screen "equals" symbol in the filename passed to shell command in R's `system()`

Tags: r

I am calling `system()` under Windows to open the file. I wrap the filename in quotes so I don't have any problems with spaces for example - but surprisingly the `=` symbol still causes problems:

```
saveopen <- function(df, fn){
  write.table(df, fn)
  #system(command = paste0('cmd /C "', fn, '"')) # try without shQuote
  system(command = paste0('cmd /C ', shQuote(fn)) )
}

data(iris)

saveopen(iris,'1A_iris.txt') # works

saveopen(iris,'1A iris.txt') # works

saveopen(iris,'1A=iris.txt') # fails: 
# '1A' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
# operable program or batch file.

# Same if I just call it directly:
system(command = 'cmd /C "1A iris.txt" ') # works
system(command = 'cmd /C "1A=iris.txt" ') # fails
# '1A' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
# operable program or batch file.

# Tried with system2 but somehow it doesn't work at all:
system2(command = 'cmd /C "1A iris.txt" ') # nope
```

Comment: Can you try with `system2` or try wrapping the command with `shQuote`

Comment: with `system2` somehow it doesn't work at all for any option. `shQuotes` works with space but not with `=`. I will add these details to the question, thanks for the input!

Comment: And, just to be clear, `cmd /C "1A=iris.txt"` works fine when you call it in the windows command prompt directly? What command are you trying to run? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @MrFlick what I am trying to do is to open the file using the default system handler (which in Windows is defined by the file's extension). If I open `cmd` window "console", I can't run `cmd` command from it, but I can just enter the command like `"1A=iris.txt"` (just the filename) - and it will work.